# THttpClient is not working on some machines

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

My application needs to connect to my website. The code snippet works perfectly fine on most machines. However some users complain it's not working despite they have internet connection.

```
uses System.Net.HttpClient;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HttpClient: THttpClient;
  HttpResponse: IHttpResponse;
begin
  HttpClient := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
    try
      HttpResponse := HttpClient.Get('http://mywebsite.com');
    except
      on E:exception do
        showmessage(E.Message);
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Text := HttpResponse.ContentAsString();
  finally
    HttpClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I can reproduce the error message by using the [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/) software. Sandboxie allows internet connection to my application but my application displays error. The error message is exactly this:

> Error sending data: (1752) The server endpoint cannot perform the
> operation

The problem arises when I try both http or https websites.

EDIT: When I try using TIdHttp (see below), the same application can connect. But I want a non-Indy solution.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PostData: TStringList;
begin
  PostData:=TStringlist.Create;
  Memo1.Lines.Text:=IdHTTP1.Post('http://mywebsite.com',PostData); // WORKS!
end;
```

EDIT2: I think I will use TIdHttp (http only) as 2nd try. It will work for everybody.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you need to move the call to `ContentAsString()` inside the `try` block. If `Get()` raises an exception, the assignment of `HttpResponse` will be skipped, so calling `ContentAsString()` outside of the `try` block will crash.

Comment: Hi Remy. I just wanted to show the error message caused by that line. Thanks, any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Cant you inspect the data regarding the request service side and compare the working and non working requests? Maybe it’s a server side issue...

Comment: @R.Hoek No, it's absolutely client issue. No request log exists in server side. The problemeatic clients can't connect to any website using the code snippet above. But their browser can connect everywhere.

Comment: I’ve also had some trouble depending on the virus defense suite installed on the machine (or just with the default Windows Defender suite)....

Comment: Always check the UserAgent.on your component. Many places automatically filter out anything that says "Indy Library".